# Viewport Navigation controls

Tags: unreal-4

I'm encountering an issue: I cannot move into my view with `W`, `A`, `D`, `S`. However `UP`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `DOWN` arrows work. What's wrong?

Here's my viewport navigation configuration:

[Viewport navigation key binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDwOq.png)

Comment: The docs say "by default you must hold RMB [Right Mouse Button] to use the WASD game-style controls" — can you confirm you're doing that?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry... I didn't see this part of the doc... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, always [consult the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UI/LevelEditor/Viewports/ViewportControls/index.html):

> ### Game-style
>
> The WASD controls will feel natural to those who are used to playing shooter games on the PC. They are enabled by default and can be used **whenever you are holding RMB**. This means you will still use RMB to turn the camera while navigating in this way.
>
> These controls are mirrored on the arrow keys and num pad to provide alternate access to them.
>
> All of these controls are only valid in a Perspective viewport, and by default **you must hold RMB** to use the WASD game-style controls.

Here, "RMB" means the right mouse button (or secondary button, if you're using a different mouse configuration).